# Replace Strings in java having metacharacters

Tags: regex, string, replace, metacharacters

I have two strings and want to replace one string from the other. The problem is that strings have meta characters.

E.g.

```
String string1 = "I am foo";
String string2 = "I am bar and I am foo. I am both.";
string2 = string2.replaceAll(string1, ""); does the replacement.
```

Suppose I have the following strings.

```
String string1 = "I + am - foo [].";
String string2 = "I + am bar and I + am - foo []. I am both.";

Then the answer should be : "I + am bar and I am both."
```

How can we perform the replacement?
I know
`java.util.regex.Pattern.quote("xyz")` escapes the characters, but in this case, there are many meta characters.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand why `Pattern#quote()` does not work here. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you already have the answer:

```
String string1 = "I + am - foo [].";
String string2 = "I + am bar and I + am - foo []. I am both.";
System.out.println(string2.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(string1), ""));
```

Output:

```
I + am bar and  I am both.
```